# Different DPI on Ubuntu from sudo and user

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, dpi

I recently experienced very strange thing. When I start my Java app like

```
sudo java -jar ./myapp.jar
```

it looks exactly as it was designed:

[image]

But if I start without sudo

```
java -jar ./myapp.jar
```

It looks different:

[image]

Edit fields are smaller. Buttons has another design.. etc..

What am I missing here?

P.S. It happens both on Ubuntu 14 and 16

Comment: make sure you dont have two seperate java versions for root and user.

Comment: Good idea. Just checked - its the same 1.8.0._151 for both

Comment: Looks like you have same DPI, but different Look&Feel.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

It's all about Ubuntu interface theme.

Should run as follows:
java -Dswing.systemlaf=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel -jar